# How to add a handler to root logger that only handles events from a particular sub logger

Tags: python, python-logging

I'm trying to wrap my head around python logging module's hierarchical design. I have a particular logger `A.B.C` that needs a very specific handler. But it seems to me that attaching a handler directly to `A.B.C` is somewhat of an anti-pattern and even if I do that events are propagated all the way to the root logger anyway (unless I do `logger.propagate = False`). The official documentation says:

> A common scenario is to attach handlers only to the root logger, and to let propagation take care of the rest.

What is the best-practice to deal with this? If I'm using my package directly I'll define and configure the root logger myself and I can attach a handler for `A.B.C` to the root logger but how do I make it only handler events originating from `A.B.C`. And if I'm using my python package as a library in some other program I don't want to have a handler for `A.B.C`.

Comment: I'm confused where you got the idea that using logger-specific handlers is an anti-pattern. That's exactly why the logger hierarchy exists in the first place. Jerry-rigging anything else _would_ be an anti-pattern.

Comment: _"And if I'm using my python package as a library in some other program"_ library packages shouldn't configure loggers at all. Logging configuration should always be left to the end application.

Comment: I mean, I quoted the official document but maybe you're not wrong. To me what it says about attaching handlers to root makes sense because it makes logging work both when you're running as the top-level program and when the package is used a library. If I attach a handler to some sub logger then you'd get unwanted logs in library mode.

Comment: By "library packages shouldn't configure loggers at all." you mean they shouldn't configure handlers right?

Comment: The docs say "A common scenario is" not "it's best practice to". That passage is saying "often, you don't need different handlers for all of your loggers. If that's the case, you can just add handlers to root logger instead instead of configuring the same handlers on each logger."

Comment: That doesn't quote answer my question but thank you for your contribution.

Comment: re #2: Not just handlers. Library code shouldn't configure anything on any loggers. Any configuration that your library does may be invalidated by the application's logging config and/or can lead to configuration race conditions (which are _really_ annoying to debug). As a rule, library code should only call `logging.getLogger` (but not at import time). Everything else should be configured downstream